# List polymorphic inheritance choices and create an instance based on that choice

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a joined tables inheritance, for example Animal, Cat, and Dog.  I want to allow the user to create a new Animal.

Is there a way to get all the types (cat, dog) into a list for the user?  Is there a way to take the user's choice and create an instance out of it?  (I don't want to hard-code `if choice == "cat": Cat()`.)

Comment: Do you want to allow the user to add classes in python or do you want the user to be able to add tables in a database? Or Both? Do you want the user to register or do you want the code to automatically introspect for the answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQLAlchemy tracks the polymorphic children of a parent model.  Use [`inspect`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/core/inspection.html) on the `Animal` model to find a [mapping of polymorphic identities](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/mapping_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.mapper.Mapper.polymorphic_map).

```
>>> from sqlalchemy import inspect
>>> i = inspect(Animal)
>>> i.polymorphic_map
{'cat': <Mapper at 0x7fb4c7a8b390; Cat>,
 'dog': <Mapper at 0x7fb4c7a98240; Dog>}
```

You can get the class from the mapper with the [`class_`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/mapping_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.mapper.Mapper.class_) attribute.

```
>>> i.polymorphic_map['cat'].class_
__main__.Cat
```

With these two pieces, you can now get a list of types to present to the user, and you can instantiate a model based on the value chosen.

```
types = inspect(Animal).polymorphic_map.keys()
user_input = 'cat'
new_cat = inspect(Animal).polymorphic_map[user_input]()
```

If there are more levels to the hierarchy, such as `CalicoCat` and `HairlessCat`, you can use [`polymorphic_iterator`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/mapping_api.html?highlight=polymorphic_map#sqlalchemy.orm.mapper.Mapper.polymorphic_iterator) to look at the entire hierarchy.